# MySql inserting a value greater than allowed limit

Tags: mysql

My SQL as follows:

```
create table test (
id tinyint unsigned,
id2 smallint unsigned
);

insert into test values ( 333, 66666);

select * from test

+------+-------+
| id   | id2   |
+------+-------+
|  255 | 65535 |
+------+-------+
```

I am aware that the max for `tinyint` is 255 and the max for `smallint` is 65,535. What I am curious about is how the result above came about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

> Setting a numeric column to a value that lies outside the column's
>   range. The value is clipped to the closest endpoint of the range.

You should have seen a warning regarding this as well. Note that in `STRICT` mode this will fail with an [error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_warn_data_out_of_range) unless you use `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.